# Combine powerpoint presentations without changing template/background?

Tags: ms-office

I have multiple powerpoint presentations that need to be combined into a single presentation. They have different templates/background slides. This seems to be rather straightforward to do on Windows, but I can't find any online documentation for how to do this on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, this feature is not currently available in PowerPoint 2016 for Mac. If you would like to request this feature, please leave us your feedback at the [PowerPoint for Mac User Voice Forum](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288925-powerpoint-for-mac). This will help us prioritize new features in future updates.

<sup>https://support.office.com/client/Can-I-compare-and-combine-two-PowerPoint-2016-for-Mac-presentations-fc614567-0939-4842-aa24-5eca01a356a5?NS=MACPOWERPOINT&Version=16&AppVer=MPP160</sup>

The link in the help article goes to the general PowerPoint UserVoice page. The specific feature request on UserVoice can be found at:

- https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288925-powerpoint-for-mac/suggestions/10966962-please-add-the-ability-to-compare-and-combine-two